# Whenever trying to toggle, it always switches to true no matter what way I try to toggle

Tags: javascript, boolean

Logs
[image]

Code that displays the logs
[image]

So, I have an HTML button hooked up to run the function shown in the code above, and I've tried many ways like using different toggle functions such as `bool = bool ? false : true;` but none work. I've tried to insert the `hideToggled = !hideToggled` in other places, like both the if functions, or below the if functions, but neither seems to work. Any help would be extremely appreciated!

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Anyway, there is a typo. `=` is assignment and `==` and `===` test for equality.

Comment: Oh, sorry, didn't know I wasn't supposed to upload images. I notice the typo now, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are assigning your variable true/false value in the `if` blocks

`if (hideToggled = true)`

will result in hideToggled to be assinged the value true

Check out the working code below:

```js
let hideToggled = false
let hideButtonText = ''

function toggleHideShow() {
  hideToggled = !hideToggled

  if (hideToggled) {
      hideButtonText = 'Show'
  } else {
      hideButtonText = 'Hide'
  }
}

toggleHideShow()
console.log(hideToggled, hideButtonText)
toggleHideShow()
console.log(hideToggled, hideButtonText)
toggleHideShow()
console.log(hideToggled, hideButtonText)
toggleHideShow()
console.log(hideToggled, hideButtonText)
```

Comment: Thank you! God, I feel like an idiot forgetting basic syntax...